# Concatenating <select> with data from json when I change option

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wrote some code to get `<select>`s from a Json file. My code generates new selections according to the Json levels available: I have a first selection and, if the option selected has a second selection concatenated, a new `<select>` comes out with its options. It goes ahead until I reach the "leaf" of the tree. Everything is good so far. Anyway, if I change the option of the previous select, I get one more select appended to the latest one. What I need, instead, is to change the values of the latest option according to the changings of the previous one I made.

**Example**

1 --> 1.1 --> 1.1.1 If I turn "1.1" into "1.2"

I get: 1 --> 1.2 --> 1.1.1 --> 1.2.1 .

What i want to get is: 1 --> 1.2 --> 1.2.1

Comment: Just to get you right. You currently have, fort example, `1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1` and you then turn `1.1` into `1.2` and expect the new numeration of objects to be `1 -> 1.2 -> 1.2.1`. So you expect the 2 in level 2 to be applied also in all the other nested levels? Is that correct?

Comment: add data-level params while appending. when option is changes remove record of the selected level using attr method.

Comment: @DiabolicWords correct I expect to apply this logic to all nested levels if there are any.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to solve it without having more information but it's impossible. Do you see any chance to put your app on a plunkr-page or post all the code (HTML, JSON, JavaScript) here? I think I have a good approach, but I miss some relevant piece of information...

Comment: @DiabolicWords here's the link: https://codepen.io/McKenzie10/pen/XYOGLe --Thanks

Comment: Okay. My first try ended up in a dead end street. I'll continue in 5 to 6 hours.

Comment: thank you @DiabolicWords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have a second solution. Use the UTC-Millisecs of Date().getTime() as ID. Every new `<select>` will always have a numerically larger ID than the one you're clicking. Should work the same way without being forced to adjust the optionIds. I changed all IDs back to 5 digits length.

```
function createSelect(source) {
  var select = $('<select>');
  // add an additional field in order to be able to choose all real options from start
  var headline = $('<option>').attr('value', 0).html('-- choose --');
  select.append(headline);

  // for-loop

  // the current UTC-millisecs become the ID
  select.attr('id', new Date().getTime());

        select.change(function() {
        // Get the ID of the current select
        const currentID = Number(this.id);

           // remove every element from DOM that has a larger id
           $( "select" ).each( function(index, element) {
              let otherID = Number(element.id);

              if(otherID > currentID) {
                  document.getElementById(this.id).remove();
              }         
           });

  // the rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Here is another solution. This time the optionId doesn't matter. If this helped you, please upvote the answer by clicking the  up-arrow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally have a solution. Hope this suites your expectations. I had to restructure your object a little. But the most important change is the length of the optionId's. Please note that the ids are one digit longer with each level. Thus, you have a possibility to figure out on what level a change took place. Then you remove all the levels below and rebuild them afterwards with the according values. That's it.

```
 function createSelect(source) {
  var select = $('<select>');
  // add an additional field in order to be able to choose all real options from start
  var headline = $('<option>').attr('value', 0).html('-- choose --');
  select.append(headline);

  // for-loop  

  // the id of the last option field of each select field 
  // becomes the id of the select field
  select.attr('id', object.id);

  select.change(function() {
      // Get the ID of the current select
      // define max length by evaluating the length of the current select element's id
      const maxIdLength = this.id.length;

      // remove every element from DOM that has a larger id length
      $( "select" ).each( function(index, element) {
          let idLength = element.id.length;

          if(idLength > maxIdLength) {
              document.getElementById(this.id).remove();
          }         
      });

 // the rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Here you go. I'd really appreciate if you would mark this answer as solution and give me an additional upvote. ;)

Comment: optionId have always the same length but have a progressive number. How could deal with?

Comment: How would you display dynamically and accordingly the options selected by user in a <p> tag? Like: 1 + 1.1 + 1.1.1 - Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please, put this follow up question in another post and give me the link to it via comment in this post here. I'll then have a look at it.